# can't create a record in a database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, controller

I am using rails version 4.2 and ruby version 2.2.0. I am trying to save a record to **`lollypops`** table. No exceptions indicating reasons.

TASK: As soon as a `member` is created and saved, I want to populate the **`lollypops`**  table by calling the `create_lollypop(@member.id)` in members controller's `create` method like this:

```
 #   POST /members
 #   POST /members.json
  def create

 @member = Member.create(members_params)                               
   return unless request.post?

   @member.save!
   self.current_user = @member
   c = Country.find(@member.country_id)
   @member.update_attributes(
   :country_code=>c.code)
   create_lollypop(@member.id) #From here I want to create lollypop
   MemberMailer.signup_notification(@member).deliver_now

   redirect_to(:controller => '/admin/members', :action => 'show',
   :id=> @member.id)
   flash[:notice] = "Thanks for signing up! Check your email now to 
   confirm that    your email is correct!"

   rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
   load_data
   render :action => 'new'

  end

def create_lollypop(member_id)
 @member = Member.find(member_id)      
    Lollypop.create(
    :member_id=>@member.id,
    :product_name=>'lollypop',
    :product_price=>100,
    :email=>@member.email,
    :house_flat => @member.house_flat,    
    :street=>@member.street,
    :city_town=>@member.city_town,
    :country =>@member.country,   
    :postcode_index=>@member.postcode_index,
    :name=>@member.name)
end
```

The 'member' is created but the 'lollypops' table is not populated. The associations are:

**MEMBER model:**

```
 has_one :lollypop, :dependent=>:destroy
```

**LOLLYPOP model**

```
  belongs_to :member
```

If I use generic SQL command then the `lollypops` table gets populated but I do not want to do that:

```
def self.create_lollypop(member_id)
   member = Member.find(member_id) 
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("insert into lollypops (member_id,product_name,product_price,email,house_flat,street,city_town,country,postcode_index,name)
   values(#{member.id},'lollypop',#{100},'#{member.email}','#{member.house_flat}','#{member.street}','#{member.city_town}','#{member.country_code}','#{member.postcode_index}','#{member.name}')")  

end
```

Any advice would be welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: Is there some validations in lollipop model?

Comment: change `Lollypop.create` to `Lollypop.create!`, you're not handling failures, so  this will raise an error, simplest way to find what's wrong.

Comment: Could you check your "create_lollypop()" once ,you are using  '@member'.

Answer (score 0):

In your create_lollypop(), You are not defining @member.

```
def create_lollypop(member_id)
  @member = Member.find member_id
  Lollypop.create!(
    :member_id=>@member.id,
    :product_name=>'lollypop',
    :product_price=>100,
    :email=>@member.email,
    :house_flat => @member.house_flat,    
    :street=>@member.street,
    :city_town=>@member.city_town,
    :country =>@member.country,   
    :postcode_index=>@member.postcode_index,
    :name=>@member.name
  )
end
```

Also use create! so in case any validation failed then it will raise exception. So it will help you sort out issue.

Comment: see, she's calling `create_lollypop` in the same request she's creating the member, so the `@member` is still available in the same scope, it's a bit different, but it should work, the accessing `@member` part at least

Answer (score 0):

For the moment try to create lollypop using the association method create_lollypop directly in your controller. use  this code in you create controller method, note that create_lollypop method will fill (member_id field automatically):

```html
@member = Member.create(members_params)                               
   return unless request.post?

   @member.save!
   self.current_user = @member
   c = Country.find(@member.country_id)
   @member.update_attributes(
   :country_code=>c.code)
   #From here I want to create lollypop
   @member.create_lollypop(
     :product_name=>'lollypop',
    :product_price=>100,
    :email=>@member.email,
    :house_flat => @member.house_flat,    
    :street=>@member.street,
    :city_town=>@member.city_town,
    :country =>@member.country,   
    :postcode_index=>@member.postcode_index,
    :name=>@member.name
    )
   MemberMailer.signup_notification(@member).deliver_now

   redirect_to(:controller => '/admin/members', :action => 'show',
   :id=> @member.id)
   flash[:notice] = "Thanks for signing up! Check your email now to 
   confirm that    your email is correct!"

   rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
   load_data
   render :action => 'new'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly an answer, more like tips and notes, it's a little long and I hope you don't mind.

- ```
  return unless request.post?
  ```

  This is more of a php thing not a rails thing, in rails already the routing is checking this, so you don't need to do this check inside the controller, if it isn't a `post` it will be routed elsewhere.
- ```
  @member = Member.create(members_params)
  return unless request.post?
  @member.save!
  ```

  Saving after creating is meaningless, because create already saves the data, if you are doing it for the sake of the bang `save!`, then you could use the create with bang `create!`, not to mention that you do the redirection check after the member's create, so if this did work, it would leave you with stray members.
- ```
  c = Country.find(@member.country_id)
  @member.update_attributes(:country_code=>c.code)
  ```

  If you have your assocciations correctly, you don't need to save the code like this, because the member knows that this `country_id` belongs to a country.

  So add this to the member model

  ```
  class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :lollypop, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :country
  end
  ```

  This way you could always call `@member.country` to return the country object, then the code could come from there, like `@member.country.code`, or you could just write a method to shorten that up

  ```
  def country_code
    country.code
  end
  ```

  this way will get the code through an extra query, but it has an advantage, if you for any reason change a country's code, you don't need to loop on all members who have that country and update their codes too, you could also shorten this up even more using `#delegate`
- ```
   @member.save!
   @member.update_attributes(:country_code=>c.code)
  ```

  Here you are updating the attributes of member after saving the member, which is kinda a waste, because you are doing 2 queries for what could be done with 1 query, programmatically it is correct and it will work, but it's bad for scaling, when more users start using your app the database will be more busy and the responses will be slower.

  Instead i would recommend to postpone the creation of member till you have all the data you want

  ```
  @member = Member.new(members_params) # this won't save to the database yet
  @memeber.code = Country.find(@member.country_id).code
  @member.save
  ```

  This will only do 1 query at the end when all data is ready to be saved.
- ```
  redirect_to(:controller => '/admin/members', :action => 'show', :id=> @member.id)
  ```

  This is ok, but you probably have a better shorter path name in your routes, something like `members_admin_path`, check your routes name by doing a `bin/rake routes` in your terminal.

  ```
  redirect_to members_admin_path(id: @member)
  ```
- ```
  redirect_to ...
  flash[:notice] = "message"
  ```

  I'm not sure this will work, because the redirection needs to be returned, but when you added the flash after it, either the redirection will happen without the flash, or the flash will be set and returned as it's the last statement, but the redirection won't happen, not sure which will happen, to fix it you can simply swap the two statements, create the flash first and then redirect, or use the more convenient way of setting the flash while redirecting, cause that's supported

  ```
  redirect_to ....., notice: 'my message'
  ```
- ```
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
  load_data
  render :action => 'new'
  ```

  This will do the job, but it isn't conventional, people tend to use the soft `save` and then do an if condition on the return value, either true or false, here's a short layout

  ```
  # prepare @member's data
  if @member.save
    # set flash and redirect
  else
    load_data
    render :new
  end
  ```
- The lollypop creation
  Now there's a few things about this, first you have the method in the controller, which is bad cause it shouldn't be the controller's concern, the second method the `self.create_lollypop` is better cause it's created on the model level, but it's a class method, then the better way is creating it as a member method, this way the member who creates the `lollypop` already knows the data because it's his own self, notice i don't need to call `@member` because i am already inside member, so simple calls like `id`, `email` will return the member's data

  ```
  # inside member.rb
  def create_lollypop
    Lollypop.create!(
      member_id: id,
      product_name: 'lollypop',
      product_price: 100,
      email: email,
      house_flat: house_flat,
      street: street,
      city_town: city_town,
      country: country,   
      postcode_index: postcode_index,
      name: name
    )
  end
  ```

  if you want you can also add this as an after create callback

  ```
  after_create :create_lollypop
  ```

  ps: This method name will probably conflict with the ActiveRecords `create_lollypop` method, so maybe you should pick a different name for this method.

Comment: Thank you Mohammad for commenting my codings. I am an amateur programer, so your analysis are valuable to me.

Answer (score 0):

As Mohammad had suggested to me, I changed Lollypop.create to Lollypop.create! and 
while running my code, one validation error popped up. After correcting it and 
altering my code to:

```
 Lollypop.create!( 
 :member_id=> @member.id,  
 :product_name=>'lollypop',
 :product_price=>100,
 :email=>@member.email,
 :house_flat => @member.house_flat,    
 :street=>@member.street,
 :city_town=>@member.city_town,
 :country =>@member.country_code,   
 :postcode_index=>@member.postcode_index,
 :name=>@member.name
)
```

The 'lollypops' table got populated.

[image]